# Renormalizability of QFTs having a finite spatial extent of particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, renormalization

Suppose we model elementary particles by fields but with the internal degrees of freedom being the Hilbert space of a [quantum rotor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_rotor_model). The spin measurements correspond to the internal angular momentum measurements of this rotor. This corresponds to an infinite dimensional internal degree of freedom, which is a reducible representation of $SO(3)$.

Classically, this model would correspond to spinning particles that have a spatial extent. Does this have any impact on renormalizability of the QFT, since point particles lead to non-renormalizability?

Comment: What about scalar particles?